# Inserting the value of a button into a text field

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a total beginner and attempting to make a calculator in Javascript.

When I click on a button I want the value of that button inserted in to a  textfield?

Here what i tried and had zero result.

```
<!-- Html Coding --->

<form name="cal">
<input name="text1" type="text" placeholder="enter value here" /><br/>
<input name="num1" type="button" value="1" onClick="num1()"/>
</form>

<!-- JavaScript coding --->
<script>
function num1()
{
    document.cal.text1.value = "1";
    }
</script>
```

Please keep it as simple as possible because im not a native English

Comment: Function name was problem (num1 is not proper function name, you can use it with underscore, like this num_1), in this case. However, you should place all in just one function: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lzyeuws/ (and avoid inline javascript, but, that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberClick(value) {
    document.cal.text1.value = value;
}
<form name="cal">
<input name="text1" type="text" placeholder="enter value here" /><br/>
<input name="num1" type="button" value="1" onClick="numberClick(this.value)"/>
<input name="num2" type="button" value="2" onClick="numberClick(this.value)"/>
<input name="num3" type="button" value="3" onClick="numberClick(this.value)"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Html Coding --->


<input name="text1" type="text" placeholder="enter value here" /><br/>
<input name="num1" type="button" value="1" onClick ="num1(this)"/>
<input name="num2" type="button" value="2" />
<input name="num3" type="button" value="3" />


<!-- JavaScript coding --->
<script>
function num1(obj)
{
    $('input[name=text1]').val($(obj).attr("value"));
}
</script>
```

> **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qq7qe4hu/)**

Answer (score -1):

i got this code for calculator with html and javascript, this will help you, use only for reference

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var flag=0,a,b,c;
function perform(value)
{
if(flag==0)
{
b=parseInt(value);
a=f1.t1.value;
document.f1.t1.value='';
flag=1;
}
else
{
c=f1.t1.value;
document.f1.t1.value='';
if(b==1)
{
var d=parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(c);
document.f1.t1.value=d;
}
else if(b==2)
{
var d=parseFloat(a)-parseFloat(c);
document.f1.t1.value=d;

}
else if(b==3)
{
var d=parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(c);
document.f1.t1.value=d;
}
else
{
var d=parseFloat(a)/parseFloat(c);
document.f1.t1.value=d;
}
flag=0;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body><center>
<font color="green" size="6" face="elephant"><b><u>CALCULATOR</u></b></font>
</br></br></br>
<table border="2" bordercolor="green" cellpadding="2" >
<tr>
<td><form name="f1">
<input type="text" name="t1" id="txt1">
</form></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><form name="f2">
<input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='1'" >
<input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='2'">
<input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='3'">
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="perform(1)"></br>
<input type="button" value=" 4 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='4'">
<input type="button" value=" 5 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='5'">
<input type="button" value=" 6 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='6'">
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="perform(2)"></br>
<input type="button" value=" 7 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='7'">
<input type="button" value=" 8 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='8'">
<input type="button" value=" 9 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='9'">
<input type="button" value=" * " onclick="perform(3)"></br>
<input type="button" value=" 0 " onclick="document.f1.t1.value+='0'">
<input type="button" value=" / " onclick="perform(4)">
<input type="button" value=" = " onclick="perform(value)">
<input type="reset" value= " clr " onclick="document.f1.t1.value='' ">
</form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```